# How to open a new window and execute a method in the new window ?

Tags: javascript

I have a button on   html page. When I click this button, some changes happen on this page .

I need the following : when i click the button, I want a new window with the same url to open, and that method to execute in that new window .

THis is what I tried

```
   <button class="button" onClick="window.open('myUri'); myMethod();"><span class="icon">Open</span></button>
```

But this does not work . How can I do this ?

Comment: Put a `<script>` tag before the end of the `<body>` tag, then call an function, say, `openWindow()` to open the new window. Avoid using the javascript in the actual `onclick`.

Answer (score 0):

You `myMethod()` won't be able to pass to the new window. You can try to call the `myMethod()` in the `onLoad` event in your new window.

If you do not have control of the content of this new window, say you are opening someone else's website, then it is simply impossible.